# SQL Server Split

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a SQL Server table with rules (length - 3) and subtype rules (length - 2) columns of datatype varchar(3) and varchar(2) respectively, stored as

```
380 244387
```

How can I get them as

```
380 24
380 43
380 87
```

If I have an odd

```
380 44387
```

how can I get them as

```
380 4
380 43
380 87
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you store non atomic data in column without separator? And why not `380 2; 380 443; 380 87`?

Comment: i was informed, we combined it for uniqueness

Comment: is it safe to assume that the datatypes are always `varchar(n)` prior to the space and `char(2)` for sub rules? Otherwise, how do you differentiate between subrule '124' and subrules '1', '2' and '4'?

Comment: A little curious about the title - "reverse concatenation"  - how does that  work

Comment: data type is of varchar , we only have 2 digit subrules, but due to some data irregularities, '0' before single digit numbers are lost. even it has to be corrected.

Comment: Are sub rules unique, or can the sub rule 22 be part of 2 main rules? Are the sub rules sorted or can they be entered as 22|43|31? I will try to cook you up a 'manageable' solution to salvage something out, but please read about normalization and work with atomic data.

Comment: subrules can be part of two main rules, and subrules are sorted. Thanks for your assistance and time.

Comment: @Coffee to answer your question, "reverse concatenation" doesn't really exist, OP  simply meant to split up a concatenated field.

Comment: thank you, updated tittle accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in a reliable fashion because the data you entered isn't [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) (only 1 entry is associated with each result). You have absolutely no way to differentiate between

```
380 1
380 14
380 280
```

and

```
380 11
380 42
380 80
```

or even

```
380 1
380 2
380 3
380 4
```

and

```
380 12
380 34
```

Please rephrase your question in a way that there is a valid answer, and at that point it will be possible to help you.

---

[First version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c9fc/4) is up but I should get back to you with a better version eventually.

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
Select a, b from BADTABLE;

OPEN cur;

DECLARE @mainID varchar(3), @string varchar(30);
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @mainID, @string;


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    WHILE LEN(@string)>2
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO GOODTABLE VALUES (@mainID, RIGHT(@string, 2));
        SET @string = LEFT(@string, LEN(@string)-2);
    END
    INSERT INTO GOODTABLE VALUES (@mainID, @string);
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @mainID, @string;  
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

In this case, I had a `BADTABLE`with varchar(3) and varchar(30) which represents your non-atomic concatenated values, and a `GOODTABLE` with varchar(3) and varchar(3) which represents the data you wanted.

Comment: I would just add 1 Normal Form - store atomic data. So many rules violated in OP example

Comment: Well, atomic data is obviously the best solution (for those wondering why, read about normalization), but comma separated values can still be worked with at least.

Comment: yes atomic data is best , we are trying to optimize our old data.

Comment: @snc I've got you somethign to work with, but I will try to do something better once I have more time.

Comment: Thanks for your time and assistance @JulienBlanchard

Comment: Personally I would insist that you store data properly in a  related table and fire the original designer for gross incompetence. @JulienBlanchard is correct, there is no way to tell where the breaks should be.

Comment: @HLGEM that's assuming there was an original designer to begin with... Sometimes it's just an HR person doing something with Access to solve one of the company's issues. Otherwise, there are *some* ways, but it's not 100% deterministic depending on what data was entered. There's definitely a way to fragment results to show all possible declinations of one entry however.